# Bott&Tu, Definition of the Euler class of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

I have a question while reading chapter 11 of Bott&Tu, *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*. The book first defines the Euler class of an oriented sphere bundle (a fiber bundle with fiber $S^n$), and then defines the Euler class of an oriented vector bundle as follows:

If $E$ is an oriented vector bundle, the complement $E^0$ of its zero section has the homotopy type of an oriented sphere bundle. The Euler class of $E$ is defined to be that of $E^0$. (p.118)

But how do we know that the Euler class of $E^0$ is well-defined? Is there a unique oriented sphere bundle that has the homotopy type of $E^0$?

Comment: One can *canonically associate* an oriented sphere bundle to each oriented real vector bundle; perhaps this is what the authors were referring to? Depending on the definition of homotopy type being used, this may not be the only oriented sphere bundle equivalent to $E\setminus E_0$.

Comment: I don't agree with Kajelad that such an association is canonical. The way I think about obtaining a sphere bundle is via a _choice_ of metric. The sphere bundle you get is then obtained by taking the unit sphere in each fiber. The key is that for any metric you choose, you can find a deformation retraction from $E\setminus E_0$ onto the unit sphere bundle. Further, you can choose this retraction so that it respects the projection onto the base. This tells you that the fiber homotopy type of the sphere bundles only depends on the bundle E, hence so does the Euler class.

Comment: @JuanChi I was thinking of the quotient by the positive real numbers, which gives a canonical quotient map $q:E\setminus E_0\to S$, where $S$ is the sphere bundle, independent of any metric. We can't canonically include $S$ into $E$, or course. In any case, all of these constructions lead to isomorphic sphere bundles, which should be sufficient here.